# Switching Highcharts theme when CSS theme is changed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Okay here goes, been banging my head on the wall for this for a while now, so thought maybe it's time to seek some assistance!

I've been looking at putting in some Highcharts charts (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic/gray). Very cool charts, but I wanted to see if I could solve a specific problem.

I am running an ASP.Net webforms site,on this site I have a CSS switcher than allows an end user to click a link to change their CSS theme on the page, light or dark basically.

This is done with a menu in HTML:

```
    <ul id="nav">
        <%--parameter" doesn't do anything but it forces an update of the CSS each time it's called--%>
        <li><a href="#" rel="/Styles/lightside.css?parameter=1">Lightside</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="/Styles/Darkside.css?parameter=1">Darkside</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And a Document ready Javascript function:

```
// CSS Switcher
// Stores CSS Selection in a Cookie object using JQuery cookie plugin
// http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/
$("#nav li a").click(function () {
    $(".switch[rel='stylesheet']").attr('href', $(this).attr('rel'));
    $.cookie("css", $(this).attr('rel'), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    return false;
});
```

This switches the css files between lightside.css and darkside.css. That works fine, and is applied instantly. I wanted to see if I could apply a theme change on Highcharts as well when the CSS theme switches.

I had a read about and found this page: http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5586 - it let me get a better idea about how to change the theme.

Ultimately the problem I am having is that I can't find a way to redraw the charts each time I switch the CSS stylesheets over, as the code to draw the charts is part of the Document Ready function itself, and I can't see a way to reapply my style over the top.

The code to draw a chart is this for example:

```
var table = $('table#MainContent_GridViewUserNumbersDaily');
var skipheader = true;

// Retrieve Values into an object called ChartTable
var ChartTable = $('tbody tr', table).map(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
        'Date': $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text(),
        'User2007': $row.find(':nth-child(2)').text(),
        'User2007Diff': $row.find(':nth-child(3)').text(),
        'User2010': $row.find(':nth-child(4)').text(),
        'User2010Diff': $row.find(':nth-child(5)').text(),
        'User2013': $row.find(':nth-child(6)').text(),
        'User2013Diff': $row.find(':nth-child(7)').text(),
        'UserTotal': $row.find(':nth-child(10)').text(),
        'UserTotalDiff': $row.find(':nth-child(11)').text(),
    };
}).get();

//// All User Numbers Chart ////

var newArray = [];

// Loop through all the rows in ChartTable
for (var i = 0; i < ChartTable.length; i++) {

    // Vars
    var xData, yData, object;
    object = ChartTable[i];

    // Parse Data
    xData = parseDateTime(object["Date"]);
    yData = parseFloat(object["UserTotal"]);

    // Append to Array
    if (skipheader = true) {
        if (i != 0) {
            newArray.push([xData, yData]);
        }
    }
    else {
        newArray.push([xData, yData]);
    }
};

$('#chartUserNumbersTotal_div').highcharts({
    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minorTickInterval: (24 * 3600 * 1000) * 7, // 1 Week
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'All Useres',
        data: newArray,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }],
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Useres'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'All Useres'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

I may be able to knock up a JSFiddle of all of this if it helps, but will see if anyone can understand what I want first!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Use the `redraw` function to redraw when you want.

Comment: I did look at redraw, but could not see any way of adding that function to globally redraw the charts, or specify which ones to redraw, so did not help me so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `destroy()` function and remove old chart, then create new item with the same options:

http://jsfiddle.net/LL75c/1/

Comment: This looks more promising indeed. I'll have a play about with it but might not get around to doing so until next week!

Answer (score 0):

> This switches the css files between lightside.css and darkside.css. That works fine, and is applied instantly. I wanted to see if I could apply a theme change on Highcharts as well when the CSS theme switches.

According to my knowledge CSS is applied instantly so my guess is there's something wrong with your CSS.

If I'm mistaken you could always store the choice in a cookie like above example and reload the document?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, CSS does switch right away, but the Highcharts are drawn at Document Ready by Javascript, and it's not CSS that is used to control the colours (but Javascript settings instead) so the charts don't change with the rest of the colours. hope that makes sense?

Comment: The charts use inline styles? You can overwrite those with !important in your CSS. Like this: div { background: red !important;}

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I don't think they support True CSS at the moment, see http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3548388-allow-styles-to-be-defined-in-css. A real shame as it would make my life a bit easier!